# S6 keeps turning off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

My girlfriend has a Samsung Galaxy S6 that keeps turning itself off randomly multiple times a day (not rebooting). The only way to turn it back on again is to hold down the power and volume buttons. Has anyone else had this problem? Or more importantly has anyone got a solution?

Comment: Connect your charger, Turn the phone On and let me know still turning off?

Comment: Yes it turns off even when charging. Its not happened today at all, but the previous 3 days its done it maybe 5 times a day.

Comment: When did it start to happen? Did you install a game or application? Did the phone had any sort of contact with liquid?

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup your data
2. Flash last firmware with Odin
3. Do not install any app

Check it again if turning off happened again, Its hardware relative and you should send it for repair.

I think flash firmware will fix your issue.